# What does heroku rake and restart commands do?

Tags: heroku, command-line, heroku-toolbelt

I'm using heroku for a sort time and I have some doubts on what exactly do 2 'commands'

The first is `rake`, I've seen here some people use it and some others, use the same instructions without `rake`, so I'd like to know if there's any difference in using `rake` or not

The other is more simple: `heroku restart`
Does this only affect the database or it also affect the code?
If it only affects the database, what happens to the data?
Should I use it, or it's an emergency command?

All info explained here and related to these instructions will be really helpful

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`rake` is a deprecated call.

```
Heroku ❯ heroku help rake
Alias: rake redirects to run:rake
Usage: heroku run:rake COMMAND

 WARNING: `heroku run:rake` has been deprecated. Please use `heroku run rake` instead."
```

Basically it is/was a shortcut to running `rake` calls for Rails apps.

**You should use `heroku run rake <task>` instead.**

`heroku restart` restarts a application processes, which are explained in more detail here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/process-model

`heroku help restart` for more info.

`heroku restart` does **not** restart your database.

Comment: Thanks Clint, by the way... Were you able to look at David's response in our heroku ticket?